# Issue with Metasploit/Armitage install on Ubuntu

Tags: systemd, metasploit

I installed Metasploit via [this](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/) tutorial. I am able to run msfconsole and it works fine. However, I can't do `service metasploit start` (metasploit.service doesn't exist), and there is no file for  metasploit in`/etc/init.d`. I assume this has to do with systemd not knowing about metasploit? Any ideas how to fix this?

Armitage is also giving me the error `org.msgpack.UnpackException: parse error`, and I believe it is related to the issue above.

Comment: did you try `sudo /opt/metasploit*/ctlscript.sh start` ? https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Using-Metasploit

Answer (score 0):

I've found this fix, works for me:

1. Edit Gemfile.lock with your favorite text editor where it says: msgpack (0.6.0) 
   To say: msgpack (0.5.12)
2. Then you have to run:
   bundle install
3. Run armitage

You will have to do this each time you run msfupdate.